# How do I find and print the matches where 7 or more goals are scored from a text file in C?

Tags: c

I have been studying C Programming for some time now and I have come across a task I find really hard to solve as I simply do not know how to proceed. Basically I have to ***find and print* those matches, where 7 or more goals have been scored** getting the information from the attached text file. I have no idea how to do it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LINE 500 /* MAX NO. OF CHARACTERS FROM THE WHOLE FILE */
#define MAX_NAME 100  /* MAX NO. OF CHARACTERS OF WEEKDAY, HOME- AND GUEST TEAM */

/* DATA STRUCTURES */
struct match {
  char weekday[MAX_NAME];
  int date;
  int the_time;
  char home_team[MAX_NAME];
  char guests[MAX_NAME];
  unsigned int home_goals;
  unsigned int guest_goals;
  unsigned int spectators;
};
typedef struct match match;

/* FUNCTION PROTOTYPES */
int read_file(const char *file_name, match matches[]);

/* MAIN FUNCTION */
int main() {


  return 0;
}

/* FUNCTIONS */

/* function to read the given text-file */
int read_file(const char *file_name, match matches[]) {
  FILE *ifp;
  int match_nbr = 0;
  match games;

  ifp = fopen(file_name, "r");
  if(ifp != NULL) {
    while(fscanf(ifp, "%s %d %d %s %s %d %d %d", games.weekday, &games.date, &games.the_time,
                                                 games.home_team, games.guests, &games.home_goals,
                                                 &games.guest_goals, &games.spectators)) {
      matches[match_nbr] = games;
      match_nbr++;
    }

    fclose(ifp);
  }
  else {
    printf("The file could not be opned %s\n", file_name);
  }

  return match_nbr;
}
```

I have not opened and read from the file yet. I think that is supposed to happen in the main function, but this is basically the code I have written so far. I tried make it work, but it did nothing, so I am hoping that someone can help me out. At this point I really have no idea how to continue and what should go into the main function and what should not.

[This is the file.](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=06441959865877966032)

I had no idea where to upload it, hope this one works D:

The text file:

```
Fre     18/07 18.30     FCN - FCV       3 - 2      3.349   
Lor     19/07 17.00     SDR - AAB       0 - 0      3.228   
Son     20/07 14.00     OB  - HOB       1 - 2      6.015   
Son     20/07 17.00     SIF - FCK       0 - 0      5.416   
Son     20/07 19.00     FCM - BIF       3 - 1      9.548   
Man     21/07 19.00     EFB - RFC       0 - 1      7.257   

Fre     25/07 18.30     FCV - OB        3 - 1      2.709  
Lor     26/07 17.00     AAB - FCM       2 - 0      7.543   
Lor     26/07 19.30     FCK - FCN       2 - 1     12.496  
Son     27/07 17.00     RFC - HOB       2 - 1      6.929   
Son     27/07 19.00     EFB - SDR       1 - 1      7.170   
Man     28/07 19.00     BIF - SIF       2 - 0     15.986  

Fre     01/08 18.30     SIF - SDR       0 - 2      3.105  
Lor     02/08 15.00     FCV - FCK       2 - 2      5.127   
Lor     02/08 17.00     OB  - AAB       1 - 1      5.840   
Son     03/08 17.00     FCN - EFB       3 - 2      3.146   
Son     03/08 19.00     HOB - BIF       2 - 0      6.583   
Man     04/08 19.00     FCM - RFC       3 - 1      6.937   

Fre     08/08 18.30     RFC - FCV       1 - 0      4.599  
Lor     09/08 17.00     AAB - FCN       1 - 2      5.904   
Son     10/08 14.00     SDR - FCM       1 - 3      4.119   
Son     10/08 17.00     FCK - HOB       0 - 3     14.664  
Son     10/08 19.00     BIF - OB        1 - 1     11.116  
Man     11/08 19.00     EFB - SIF       0 - 0      5.728   

Fre     15/08 19.30     FCK - FCM       1 - 2     13.106 
Lor     16/08 18.00     AAB - EFB       1 - 1      5.319   
Son     17/08 14.00     FCV - SIF       2 - 0      1.994   
Son     17/08 17.00     BIF - SDR       2 - 0      9.962   
Son     17/08 19.00     RFC - OB        0 - 2      3.952   
Man     18/08 19.00     HOB - FCN       0 - 0      4.221   

Lor     30/08 17.00     SDR - RFC       1 - 1      2.254  
Son     31/08 13.00     SIF - AAB       2 - 2      3.067   
Son     31/08 15.00     FCM - EFB       2 - 0      6.571   
Son     31/08 17.00     FCN - BIF       0 - 3      7.689   
Son     31/08 19.00     OB  - FCK       0 - 1      9.925   
Man     01/09 19.00     HOB - FCV       3 - 1      2.682   

Fre     12/09 18.30     FCM - OB        3 - 2      7.505  
Lor     13/09 20.35     AAB - FCK       1 - 0      8.546   
Son     14/09 14.00     SIF - FCN       1 - 2      2.390   
Son     14/09 17.00     BIF - RFC       0 - 2     25.551  
Son     14/09 19.00     EFB - FCV       3 - 0      5.209   
Man     15/09 19.00     SDR - HOB       1 - 1      4.138   

Fre     19/09 18.30     RFC - SIF       1 - 0      5.126  
Lor     20/09 17.00     HOB - EFB       1 - 1      3.736   
Son     21/09 14.00     OB  - SDR       1 - 1      7.201   
Son     21/09 16.30     FCK - BIF       1 - 0     32.526  
Son     21/09 19.00     FCN - FCM       2 - 1      4.637   
Man     22/09 19.00     FCV - AAB       1 - 0      2.703   

Fre     26/09 18.30     AAB - RFC       0 - 0      5.357  
Lor     27/09 15.00     SDR - FCK       1 - 1      5.535   
Lor     27/09 17.00     SIF - HOB       2 - 2      3.081   
Son     28/09 14.00     FCM - FCV       1 - 0      6.669   
Son     28/09 19.00     EFB - BIF       2 - 2     10.650  
Man     29/09 19.00     FCN - OB        2 - 1      4.425   

Fre     03/10 18.30     HOB - FCM       1 - 5      4.968  
Lor     04/10 17.00     OB  - SIF       2 - 0      5.587   
Son     05/10 13.00     FCV - SDR       1 - 1      2.677   
Son     05/10 15.00     RFC - FCN       0 - 0      5.021   
Son     05/10 17.00     FCK - EFB       2 - 1     15.236  
Son     05/10 19.00     BIF - AAB       2 - 1     15.412  

Fre     17/10 18.30     AAB - HOB       1 - 1      9.923  
Lor     18/10 17.00     FCN - SDR       2 - 3      3.512   
Son     19/10 14.00     FCM - SIF       2 - 1      8.622    
Son     19/10 17.00     BIF - FCV       5 - 0     12.190  
Son     19/10 19.00     FCK - RFC       1 - 0     10.723  
Man     20/10 19.00     EFB - OB        2 - 0      6.478   

Fre     24/10 18.30     SIF - FCV       1 - 2      2.160  
Lor     25/10 17.00     SDR - FCM       1 - 1      4.174   
Son     26/10 14.00     RFC - OB        3 - 0      5.135   
Son     26/10 17.00     HOB - FCK       0 - 2      4.738   
Son     26/10 19.00     EFB - BIF       0 - 0     10.077  
Man     27/10 19.00     FCN - AAB       0 - 1      4.016   

Fre     31/10 18.30     FCM - FCN       2 - 0      6.543  
Lor     01/11 17.00     FCV - EFB       1 - 4      2.602   
Son     02/11 14.00     OB  - HOB       3 - 1      8.011   
Son     02/11 17.00     FCK - SDR       1 - 1     21.413  
Son     02/11 18.30     BIF - RFC       1 - 0      12.497  
Man     03/11 19.00     AAB - SIF       2 - 0      6.240   

Fre     07/11 18.30     SIF - FCM       1 - 2      3.587  
Lor     08/11 19.00     RFC - EFB       3 - 2      3.929   
Son     09/11 13.00     SDR - OB        2 - 1      4.428   
Son     09/11 15.00     AAB - FCV       2 - 0      6.369   
Son     09/11 17.00     HOB - BIF       3 - 0      4.389   
Son     09/11 19.15     FCN - FCK       0 - 0      4.567   

Fre     21/11 18.30     FCV - RFC       0 - 1      1.849  
Lor     22/11 17.00     EFB - HOB       4 - 2      6.057   
Lor     22/11 19.30     FCK - SIF       1 - 0      8.456   
Son     23/11 14.00     OB  - FCN       1 - 0      5.927   
Son     23/11 17.00     BIF - SDR       1 - 0     12.647  
Son     23/11 19.00     FCM - AAB       2 - 0      8.005   

Fre     28/11 18.30     SDR - EFB       0 - 0      2.609  
Lor     29/11 17.00     SIF - OB        0 - 1      1.866   
Son     30/11 14.00     HOB - RFC       0 - 1      3.884   
Son     30/11 17.00     FCN - BIF       2 - 0      5.168   
Son     30/11 19.00     AAB - FCK       0 - 1      7.437   
Man     01/12 19.00     FCM - FCV       2 - 1      6.778   

Fre     05/12 18.30     RFC - SDR       0 - 0      4.551  
Lor     06/12 17.00     OB  - AAB       1 - 1      5.025   
Son     07/12 14.00     FCV - HOB       1 - 1      2.377   
Son     07/12 17.00     BIF - SIF       1 - 0     19.304  
Son     07/12 19.00     FCK - FCM       3 - 0     17.499  
Man     08/12 19.00     EFB - FCN       0 - 0      5.150   

Fre     20/02 18.30     FCN - RFC       0 - 3      3.316  
Lor     21/02 17.00     SIF - EFB       1 - 3      2.247   
Son     22/02 14.00     SDR - HOB       1 - 0      3.812   
Son     22/02 17.00     FCK - FCV       2 - 0     12.631  
Son     22/02 19.00     AAB - BIF       1 - 0      7.857   
Man     23/02 19.00     FCM - OB        3 - 0      7.602   

Fre     27/02 18.30     FCV - SDR       0 - 1      1.750  
Lor     28/02 17.00     HOB - FCN       1 - 0      2.086   
Son     01/03 14.00     RFC - SIF       1 - 2      4.263   
Son     01/03 17.00     OB  - FCK       1 - 0      8.421   
Son     01/03 19.00     BIF - FCM       1 - 1     13.092  
Man     02/03 19.00     EFB - AAB       1 - 3      5.260   

Lor     07/03 17.00     FCN - SDR       4 - 0      2.389  
Son     08/03 13.00     SIF - HOB       0 - 1      2.620   
Son     08/03 15.00     FCK - BIF       3 - 1     31.223  
Son     08/03 17.00     FCM - EFB       3 - 0      9.190   
Son     08/03 19.00     AAB - RFC       2 - 1      5.670   
Man     09/03 19.00     FCV - OB        1 - 2      2.134   

Fre     13/03 18.30     RFC - FCM       1 - 2      5.463  
Lor     14/03 17.00     SDR - SIF       1 - 4      3.145   
Son     15/03 14.00     FCN - FCV       2 - 0      3.243   
Son     15/03 17.00     EFB - FCK       0 - 1      7.716   
Son     15/03 19.00     BIF - OB        2 - 0     12.791  
Man     16/03 19.00     HOB - AAB       1 - 0      6.596   

Fre     20/03 18.30     OB  - EFB       0 - 2      6.005  
Lor     21/03 17.00     FCM - HOB       3 - 0      9.202   
Son     22/03 13.00     SIF - FCN       2 - 2      1.814   
Son     22/03 15.00     AAB - SDR       1 - 4      4.644   
Son     22/03 17.00     FCV - BIF       0 - 1      4.242   
Son     22/03 19.00     FCK - RFC       1 - 1      9.520   

Lor     04/04 17.00     SDR - FCN       1 - 2      2.375  
Son     05/04 17.00     HOB - SIF       2 - 2      2.940   
Son     05/04 19.00     EFB - FCM       3 - 3      7.682   
Man     06/04 16.00     BIF - FCK       0 - 0     22.020  
Man     06/04 19.30     RFC - AAB       1 - 1      5.083   
Tir     07/04 19.00     OB  - FCV       1 - 2      4.331   

Fre     10/04 18.30     HOB - EFB       3 - 1      2.743  
Lor     11/04 17.00     RFC - FCV       1 - 1      4.557   
Son     12/04 14.00     FCN - OB        1 - 2      5.264   
Son     12/04 17.00     AAB - FCM       1 - 2      7.690   
Son     12/04 19.00     SDR - BIF       0 - 1      4.633   
Man     13/04 19.00     SIF - FCK       0 - 4      3.578   

Fre     17/04 18.30     FCM - SIF       1 - 0      9.058  
Lor     18/04 15.00     FCV - AAB       2 - 1      1.854   
Son     19/04 14.00     OB  - SDR       0 - 0      6.644   
Son     19/04 17.00     BIF - HOB       0 - 1     15.904  
Son     19/04 19.30     FCK - FCN       2 - 0     10.944  
Man     20/04 19.00     EFB - RFC       0 - 0      5.690   

Fre     24/04 18.30     EFB - OB        0 - 2      5.402  
Lor     25/04 17.00     FCN - SIF       1 - 0      3.883   
Son     26/04 14.00     SDR - AAB       0 - 3      3.615   
Son     26/04 17.00     BIF - FCV       4 - 0     12.014  
Son     26/04 19.00     RFC - FCK       3 - 0      5.777   
Man     27/04 19.00     HOB - FCM       0 - 0      4.166   

Fre     01/05 18.30     AAB - HOB       5 - 0      9.401  
Lor     02/05 17.00     SIF - SDR       2 - 2      1.965   
Son     03/05 14.00     FCV - FCN       2 - 1      1.688   
Son     03/05 17.00     FCK - EFB       2 - 1     12.892  
Son     03/05 19.00     OB  - BIF       0 - 2      9.605   
Man     04/05 19.00     FCM - RFC       5 - 2      9.039   

Fre     08/05 18.30     RFC - FCN       2 - 0      5.930  
Lor     09/05 17.00     EFB - SIF       5 - 2      6.741   
Son     10/05 14.00     HOB - SDR       2 - 2      2.787   
Son     10/05 17.00     OB  - FCM       3 - 1      6.378   
Son     10/05 19.00     BIF - AAB       1 - 1     14.061  
Man     11/05 19.00     FCV - FCK       0 - 1      3.544   

Fre     15/05 18.30     AAB - OB        0 - 2      7.506  
Son     17/05 14.00     HOB - FCV       0 - 1      2.082   
Son     17/05 17.00     SIF - BIF       0 - 2      3.996   
Son     17/05 19.00     FCM - FCK       2 - 0     11.305  
Man     18/05 18.00     FCN - EFB       1 - 3      3.019   
Man     18/05 20.15     SDR - RFC       1 - 1      2.524   

Ons     20/05 18.00     OB  - SIF       1 - 1      4.717  
Ons     20/05 20.00     FCK - AAB       1 - 0      8.127   
Tor     21/05 18.00     RFC - HOB       0 - 1      6.499   
Tor     21/05 18.00     FCV - FCM       0 - 0      2.432   
Tor     21/05 20.00     BIF - FCN       3 - 1     10.052  
Tor     21/05 20.00     EFB - SDR       2 - 3      6.060   

Son     24/05 17.00     SDR - FCV       1 - 1      5.075  
Man     25/05 13.00     FCN - HOB       4 - 2      3.392   
Man     25/05 15.00     SIF - RFC       0 - 2      2.052   
Man     25/05 17.00     FCK - OB        1 - 0     14.463  
Man     25/05 19.00     FCM - BIF       2 - 3     11.535  
Tir     26/05 19.00     AAB - EFB       1 - 0      4.793   

Son     31/05 16.00     EFB - FCV       2 - 1     10.702 
Son     31/05 16.00     RFC - BIF       1 - 1      9.143   
Son     31/05 16.00     HOB - OB        2 - 2      2.958   
Son     31/05 16.00     SDR - FCK       1 - 2      5.643   
Son     31/05 16.00     FCN - FCM       1 - 0      4.408   
Son     31/05 16.00     SIF - AAB       1 - 2      2.103   

Son     07/06 16.00     OB  - RFC       0 - 2      7.000  
Son     07/06 16.00     BIF - EFB       0 - 1     22.838  
Son     07/06 16.00     AAB - FCN       1 - 0      6.776   
Son     07/06 16.00     FCM - SDR       2 - 1     11.535  
Son     07/06 16.00     FCK - HOB       1 - 0     16.699  
Son     07/06 16.00     FCV - SIF       3 - 1      1.201
```

Comment: do you  have a sample file I can use?

Comment: Yeah, I just did. Sorry. I forgot as I was writing the post.

Comment: what I got so far is the loop continues running infintely, causing the program to write out the array boundaries. why that is happening I'm trying to figure out

Comment: I don't usually use fscanf to read files, the following link on tutorial point uses it outside of a loop:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fscanf.htm
I suggest using fgets, I have some ready code somehwere on my laptop

Comment: I would not download that file... if it is text file just paste some of it here, so that we know how it is formatted.

Comment: It's a pretty long file, but sure, I can do that!

Comment: yup it was fscanf, check my answer

Comment: It works when I compile it, but when I try to run the program, it does not return anything. Not sure why, though :/

Comment: yes I have implemented no printf() whatsoever, feel free to do so in the code.
if you're looking for the number of matches:
int match_nbr = read_file("superliga-2014-2015.txt",matches);
  printf("number of matches: %i\n",match_nbr);

if your're looking to print any of the struct members you can do so inside the loop:
printf("%s\n",games.weekday);

Comment: I am very thankful for your help so far. I cannot seem to get it to work, though. I have tried the things that you have said so far, but all it does it compile. It does not, however, return any output - and by looking at it I cannot seem to figure out the issue.

Comment: what are you trying to print? or what is the expected output

Comment: From the text file, I need to find and print those matches, where 7 or more goals have been scored.

Comment: had tp modify the struct and the sscanf to get things working, I've modified the code to print out those matches, check out the code.

Comment: has that code worked for you?

Comment: Hi Adel! 
Thank you so much for your time and help with the program. It didn't quite do as I had wished for. The idea was to print the whole line in the text file instead of just the names like you have written below the program you have pasted. Basically like: "Man     11/08 19.00     EFB - SIF       0 - 0      5.728" etc.

Answer (score 0):

that got it working, I used sscanf on the line read by fgets

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LINE 500 /* MAX NO. OF CHARACTERS FROM THE WHOLE FILE */
#define MAX_NAME 100  /* MAX NO. OF CHARACTERS OF WEEKDAY, HOME- AND GUEST TEAM */

/* DATA STRUCTURES */
struct match {
  char weekday[MAX_NAME];
  int date;
  int the_time;
  char home_team[MAX_NAME];
  char guests[MAX_NAME];
  char dash[1];
  unsigned int home_goals;
  unsigned int guest_goals;
  unsigned int spectators;
};
typedef struct match match;

/* FUNCTION PROTOTYPES */
int read_file(const char *file_name, match matches[]);

/* MAIN FUNCTION */
int main() {
  match matches[1024];
  int match_nbr = read_file("superliga-2014-2015.txt",matches);
  printf("number of matches: %i\n",match_nbr);

  return 0;
}

/* FUNCTIONS */

/* function to read the given text-file */
int read_file(const char *file_name, match matches[]) {
  FILE *ifp;
  int match_nbr = 0;
  match games;

  ifp = fopen(file_name, "r");
  char line[2048];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, ifp) != NULL) {
    sscanf(line, "%s %s %lf %s %s %s %d %s %d %d", games.weekday, &games.date, &games.the_time,
                                                 games.home_team, games.dash,  games.guests, &games.home_goals,
                                                 games.dash, &games.guest_goals, &games.spectators);
    if (games.home_goals + games.guest_goals > 6 )
      printf("%s vs %s \n",games.home_team,games.guests);
    matches[match_nbr] = games;
    match_nbr++;


}
  return match_nbr;
    fclose(ifp);
    }
```

result:
FCM vs RFC 
FCM vs RFC 
EFB vs SIF 
number of matches: 230